# Sharing Sockets in Linux and recover from process death?

Tags: linux, network-programming

I have the following problem that I have to share socket connections and a single server socket I am listening to among different processes.

I can synchronize this by creating a well definied shared memory region mapping the region among all processes and use a well defined protocol in order to interact with this region.

A process among the collaborating processes takes over this structure and handles the actual TCP socket connections for all processes sending messages using the shared memory.

To avoid concurrency issues and conjestion / race conditions a specific process has its own slots it may use to hand over or receive messages from any of those sockets.

This works good enough but when the process is ended or even crashes I need a way to hand over and use the socket connections in a way that is consistent.

As far as I understand it a socket connection is bound to the process it has created it and is going to be released on process termination.

Is there any idea how to avoid spawning another process owning the sockets?

Comment: Eh? You do the spawning. It isn't automatic. Processes crashing don't crash the system. This situation is normally handled by socket inheritance and fork(). Hard to see why you're not using that.

Comment: If the process with the entire communication crashes and I can not recover the socket connections I would rather crash the system and reboot (which one can do) instead of recover each connection with the same UUIDs of the participants. I can not come up with a good reliable recovery strategy.

Comment: I removed the crashing reboot process idea since it was miss leading. Sorry. Your hint about socket inheritance is interesting and lead to finding the correct answer. So thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the hint about the socket inheritance I noticed that Linux handles sockets using file descriptors. Using the socket API (http://linux.die.net/man/7/unix) one can use sendmsg / recvmsg to send ancillary messages containing data like permissions and file descriptors.

Using ancillary messages handing over file descriptors sockets can be shared between processes solving my problem. So if I have all processes share the sockets but only one using it, the other can step forward and take over if the current socket 'master' dies.

This way I can still use shared memory for this type of communication which is multiple times faster than using inter-process socket communication.

So thanks again EJP for your valuable input.